# How can I add sorting while looping through distinct associated elements in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a test app that models stamps collection. There's a catalog of stamps that a user can add to the collection. CollectionItem model has a bunch of belongs_to:

```
  belongs_to :stamp
  belongs_to :issue
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :country
```

On the collection index view there's a list of all collection items in a cascade manner.

Country: Issue: Stamps. Issue: Stamps. Issue: Stamps. Country: ... etc.

```
@my_collection_countries = CollectionItem.where(user: current_user).select(:country_id).distinct(:country)
```

It works as expected with this approach.

```
<% @my_collection_countries.each do |collection_item| %>
  <%= link_to collection_item.country.name, country_path(collection_item.country) %>
  <% collection_item.class.where(user: current_user, country_id: collection_item.country).select(:issue_id).distinct(:issue).each do |issue| %>
    <%= link_to issue.issue.name, issue.issue %>
      <% issue.class.includes(:stamp).where(user: current_user, country: collection_item.country, issue: issue.issue).select(:stamp_id).distinct(:stamp).order('stamps.name asc').each do |stamp| %>
        <%= link_to stamp.stamp.name, stamp.stamp %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I believe I'm doing something wrong because when I try to order issues or countries the same way as stamps they are displayed multiple times, and `distinct` doesn't help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on in your question, but you almost certainly don't want to be calling `#class` in your examples. It should work better without the call to `#class`, you can just remove it.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Without `class` I get `undefined method 'includes' for #<CollectionItem:0x00007fa21d1d27e0>`. Which part is confusing? I'd be glad to add more details.

Comment: I think you should be able to get rid of the `includes` too

Comment: You don't really need the include unless you're worried about performance

Comment: @thesecretmaster At the moment I'm not concerned about performance indeed. Making it work would be great for starters. When I remove `includes` it produces `undefined method 'where' for #<CollectionItem:0x00007fa21f351e98>`

Comment: On that line you should write `CollectionItem.where` rather than `issue.class.includes(:stamp).where`. Since `issue` is a `CollectionItem`, `issue.class == CllectionItem` and I think it makes more sense just to specify the class name. However the simplifications I originally suggest are probably not ideal now that I've taken the time to understand what your code is doing a bit more fully

Comment: I'm not sure there's a particularly good way to do what you want in SQL, but if you're ok with some rather slow ruby code you can use `#group_by` to solve your problem by doing `CollectionItem.where(user: user).group_by(&:country).each { |country, xs| xs.group_by(&:issue).each do { |issue, ys| ys.group_by(&:stamp).sort_by { |k,v| k.name }.each { |stamp, zs| }}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of to address this is by using `#group_by`, a ruby method that iterates through a collection and returns a hash of the form `{thing_being_grouped_by: [things_that_have_that_characteristic]}`. So, in your case we can use:

```
@my_collection_countries = CollectionItem.where(user: current_user).group_by(&:country).sort_by { |country,_| country.name }

<% @my_collection_countries.each do |country, xs| %>
  <%= link_to country.name, country_path(country) %>
  <% xs.group_by(&:issue).each do |issue, ys| %>
    <%= link_to issue.name, issue %>
      <% ys.group_by(&:stamp).sort_by { |stamp,_| stamp.name }.each do |stamp, zs| %>
        <%= link_to stamp.name, stamp %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Since now you're doing all the work in ruby instead of in SQL, you can no longer order things with `#order` (which adds a clause to your SQL query) but instead can order things with `#sort_by` as I've demonstrated in the innermost loop of the example.

---

While this code will incur a significant performance penalty with a large database, in a small test app this will serve you just fine. While this will be slower than a SQL solution, it's general complexity is similar, as even in SQL you still have the problem that you'll be issuing `CountryItem.where(user:current_user).count` SQL queries which in and of itself is expensive.